# is the call of a c dll function from a c client asynchronous?

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have made a simple c dll with only one function (in VS 2017). I use this dll function from another c client program. Is the call asynchronous (in a separate thread than the calling client program run)? If not then I need to run asynchronous and if the dll function is a long time process (or when it wants to notify the calling program for an event) I need a call from a dll to a callback function in the calling (client) program to  manage the event (I suppose using function pointer).

The dll code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void DllFunction() {
    for (long i = 1;i <= 300000;i++) {
        printf("dll\n");
    }

}
```

And the c client program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__declspec(dllimport) void DllFunction(void);

    int main() {
        DllFunction();
        for (long i = 1;i <= 300000;i++) {
            printf("client\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Running the previous client code I think that there was no interference between the two printf commands (dll and client)!

**Updated**

first things first... after searching i realize that we can separate the callback feature from the async call. We can have a callback function that residence in the calling (client) code and be called from a dll long time process to notify for example about the progress as very nicely described in this article:
[Using callbacks in DLLs](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9902/Using_callbacks_in_DLLs.htm)

so it remains the second problem about async... what about CreateThread() function. Can I use it? And if yes where have to be used?In the dll or in the client's code?

Comment: No, it is not asynchronous unless you make it so. C doesn't know anything about threads or asynchronous things.

Comment: I have updated my question... I separate the callback feature from async feature since they can coexist independently

Answer (score 5):

No, you can think of DLL calls as just ordinary function calls. There is nothing special happening just because the target function happens to live in a DLL.

In practice there might be an indirection table or something so there can be an extra jump, but it's still essentially just jumps directly to code, just as any other function call in your program.

If you want asynchronicity you will have to build it yourself, and making a set of functions run in a separate task/thread is not super simple.

Comment: ok... I notified it and wanted a confirmation... thanks...but can you suggest me a few points that I should follow about this?

Comment: @nonlinearly pay attention to memory management. E.g. Doing a `malloc` in the dll and freeing it in the calling code may get you into trouble, the subject is vast.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have found a solution about async...
I have mentioned that the dev environment is Visual Studio 2017. So we can use the CreateTrhead() function. We can use it either from client's code if we use the dll from a platform that support threading (Microsoft C for example like the test client program in this question) or you can use CreateThread in the dll if the dll will be used from enviroments that can not support multithreading (like VBA).
For the first situation the code is:

DLL (the same as before)

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void DLLFunction() {
    for (long i = 1;i <= 300000;i++) {
        printf("dll\n");
    }
}
```

CLIENT (we use the CreateThread() to call the DLLFunction)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllimport) void DLLFunction();

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* data) {
    DLLFunction();
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);

    for (long i = 1;i <= 300000;i++) {
        printf("client\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```